# Get image file from Base64 String Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, base64

Here is my code

```
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
```

if url variable print out to logcat will display :

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkI....

how can i do the download image file to android download directory with this base64 string?

what should i do in onDownloadStart() function?

Thanks for help

Comment: obviously something like this: if url starts with "data" remove the non base64 part then decode base64 string to byte array and save it (of course you can also decode base64 directly to output stream)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your `base64` string to `byte` array.

Please note that converting the whole `base64` string along with `data:image/jpeg;base64,` will not give you the desired output. So you have to remove that part.

You can remove the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` using the below function.

```
public static String parseBase64(String base64) {

    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=base64,).*\\s*)",Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(base64);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group().toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return "";
}
```

You can save the image as file using the below function

```
private void downloadFileFromBase64(String fileContent) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/com/myApp/img/");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
            if (fileContent != null) {
                String attachment = parseBase64(fileContent);
                byte[] byteArr = Base64.decode(attachment, Base64.DEFAULT);
                File f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(),"sample.jpg");
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(byteArr);
                fo.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        }}catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: in other link i found on google. they are using the FileOutputStream, or something like that and then write the image to memory storage. But i got a notice on FileOutputStream() function and said unhandler or something. Can you tell me what happen?

Comment: Can you be clear on what notice you got? But I'm pretty sure that this code works.

Comment: Thank you for your class. i've successfully implemented this class but the image file are downloaded can't display properly caused the image size is 0 bytes. please help. Thanks

Comment: @AndhyTaslin I have updated code, this works for me.

Comment: i had no idea for image size is 0 bytes. code from your class is work correctly but i cannot do anything with image size always empty. is there a bug are happened?
how can i  trace file write status ?

Comment: I'm sure its not a bug. You can use debugger to track what is happening in the method.
Check in `/com/myApp/img/` directory in your android mobile. I have changed the directory path in the code.

Comment: the file `sample.jpg` is created successfully on my directory : `/com/myApp/img/` but when i open the image, it's blank image with 0 bytes image size.

Comment: Can you post your base64 string? Also check your logcat if you're getting any excecption? If yes, post the logcat stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my base64 string

> data:image/jpeg;base64,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

Comment: this looks like a corrupted base64. I get `2.96 kb` as file size but the image is corrupted. Try with other base64 string.

Comment: it's what i got from stacktrace. may be this is the text that is too long to be printed on logcat.
i'm not sure what i'm doing. i got my image with 70KB image size right now. i think there is corrupted base64 string are sent from server.
Thank you very much for your solution an help. @SripadRaj

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept my answer :)